# Javascript image array issue

Tags: javascript

this is my problem: im trying to create an image selector, i mean a collection of images shown on the screen among which i can choose one and store it in a var. This is the code for the array:

```
<script typre="text/javascript">
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = new Image();
    img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
    img[1] = new Image();
    img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";

    for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        document.write(img[i]);
    };

</script>
```

When i run it, it displays  [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the image! What should i do?? Thanks all!

Comment: Did you look up [the documentation for `HTMLImageElement` that states that you should use `document.body.appendChild` instead?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `img[i]` is an object and `document.write` will write it as string representation of it by calling `img[i].toString()`.

If you want to display an image then use

```
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        document.body.appendChild(img[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg"; 
document.write(img.outerHTML);
```

Use the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property in order to display it

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious because for loop will print img[0],img[1] not src of image
You can write `img[i].src`

```js
 var img = new Array();
        img[0] = new Image();
        img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
        img[1] = new Image();
        img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
    
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            alert(img[i].src);
        };
```